# What does "a bit of a tartar" mean?

Tags: meaning, british-english

Recently, a woman I know who lives in England (OK, she's my fiancee, if you want to know), wrote to me and described someone she knows as "a bit of a tartar".  Now in context it seemed like a friendly jibe, but it I wasn't familiar with this particular construction, as an American.

Yes, yes, I could ask her what she means, but I wanted to ask it here and contribute to the knowledge base!

I found one dictionary definition in which it said that as an adjective it meant "of, relating to, or characteristic of the Tatars".  Which of course explains everything.  Not.

**Edited to Add**: Since this was posted, my fiancée has become my wife, whoo hoo!

Comment: Note for non-English speakers.  This is often confused/muddled with **"tart"**.  ("tart" just means a woman who dresses or behaves in a way that is considered tasteless or provocative.)  In general people often confuse "tart" and "tatar/tartar".  So indeed you often hear "She's a bit of a tart" as well as "she's a bit of a tartar/tatar."

Comment: An interesting observation is "bit of a tartar" is usually, I think, only applied to females, not males.  Although, seemingly, it could perfectly apply to males also.

Comment: I wouldn't rule out autocorrect. Does she use voice-to-text?

Comment: No, @bobstro, this was a quite deliberate bit of typing.  Joe, I don't see how the term could be applied to a female.  Tart, yes, Tartar, no.

Comment: Yes the definitions above are correct. If you are from the area round Dudley in the West Midlands, 'ta-ta' means a bit stupid - away with the faries - or even 'doolally-tap'

Answer (score 16, accepted):

"Characteristic of the Tartars" is basically correct. The OED describes 
them as:

*2. fig. Tartar-like; rough and violent, savage*

and

*3. fig.*

*a. A person supposed to resemble a Tartar in disposition; a rough and violent or irritable and intractable person.*

Another possible meaning, based on personal experience, is for *tartar* to mean stupid or mentally ill, presumably a play on re*tar*d. This comes from my schooldays, was probably local, and I haven't heard it used that way in decades.

Comment: Well, when I was going to a UK Grammar School in the late 60's, certain of the pupils were fond of referring to people who, in their opinion, "just didn't get it", as Philistines.  I doubt that Tartar was a play on retard, actually.  Now, my fiancee is an operating room nurse, and the bloke in question is a surgeon she works with, so your 3a there, wins the prize.

Answer (score 8):

A Tartar in this context is someone who is **domineering, bossy, overbearing**. It's a Britishism and quite old.

Technically and traditionally a Tartar (or Tatar) was one of the Mongolian hordes who overran Asia under Genghis Khan (although this may not be demographically correct).

Comment: The Tatars are a Turkic people living in Asia and Europe who were one of the five major tribal confederations (khanlig) in the Mongolian plateau in the 12th century

Comment: In Alan Bennett's The Uncommon Reader, the character of Queen Elizabeth refers to the photographer Cecil Beaton as "a bit of a tartar," and then goes on to describe him telling her to stand here or stand there, which supports the bossy/domineering definition.